# function not called in js fiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was doing some R&D on one of my problems with jquery validate, mean while the js function is not getting called in js fiddle. Here is the fiddle link [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/85KR4/173/)

```
function formSubmit(){
  if (!$("#tform").valid()) {           
    $("#tform").validate().focusInvalid();
    return false;
  } 
  document.getElementById('tform').submit();
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7k6sa/ Use `No wrap-in head` option on the left hand side. In forked fiddle I have just moved your function in top and put in alert

Comment: Thanks, that worked in jsfiddle, but my actual problem is that, the same code is not running in my jsp. I have cross checked it many times. What could be the possible reason.